# RadGrid Selecting Row for Drag and Drop is not working If AjaxControlToolKit.Config is used

Tags: asp.net, telerik, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, radgrid

I'm trying to upgrade Telerik and AjaxControlToolKit controls. With this change I'm forced to use AjaxControlToolKitManager. I have defined ControlBundle in AjaxControlTool.Config referenced under ControlBundle of ToolKitScriptManager. With this change, drag and drop of Telerik RadGrid is not working. Can you please help me on this? Please let me know if you want more details. Here is my code

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="masterPageScriptManager" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="1200" ScriptMode="Release" EnablePageMethods="true"
    EnableScriptGlobalization="true" CombineScripts="false">
    <CompositeScript>
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Common/Core.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Ajax/Ajax.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Common/jQuery.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Common/jQueryPlugins.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Common/Scrolling/ScrollingScripts.js"/>
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Common/Navigation/OData/OData.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Common/AnimationFramework/AnimationFramework.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Common/Navigation/OverlayScript.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Common/Navigation/NavigationScripts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Menu/RadMenuScripts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Menu/ContextMenu/RadContextMenuScripts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Menu/MenuItem/RadMenuItem.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Menu/Views/ClassicView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/AutoCompleteBox/RadAutoCompleteBoxScripts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Common/Popup/PopupScripts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Spell/SpellCheckService.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Common/LayoutBuilder/LayoutBuilderEngine.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Common/Widgets/Draggable.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Common/Widgets/Resizable.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Editor/RadEditor.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Dialogs/RadDialogOpenerScripts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Common/Animation/AnimationScripts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Common/TouchScrollExtender.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Window/RadWindowScripts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/Grid/RadGridScripts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/ComboBox/RadComboBoxScripts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference path = "~/Telerik/Scripts/ComboBox/Views/ClassicView.js"/>
        </Scripts>
    </CompositeScript>
    <ControlBundles>
        <ajaxToolkit:ControlBundle Name="AdminMaster" />
    </ControlBundles>
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

<ajaxControlToolkit>
    <controlBundles>  
        <controlBundle name="AdminMaster">
            <control name="ModalPopupExtender"></control>
            <control name="CalendarExtender"></control>
            <control name="CascadingDropDown"></control>
            <control name="CollapsiblePanelExtender"></control>
            <control name="AutoCompleteExtender"></control>
            <control name="FilteredTextBoxExtender"></control>
            <control name="TextBoxWatermarkExtender"></control>
            <control name="MaskedEditExtender"></control>
            <control name="MaskedEditValidator"></control>
        </controlBundle>
    </controlBundles>
</ajaxControlToolkit>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the toolkit script manager combine the scripts references? If so, can you stop it and see if things are OK?

Also, compare the scripts you load with this page to see if you have all of the needed and in the correct order: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-disabling-embedded-resources.html. You can create a simple page with the RadGrid setup, enable the Telerik scripts CDN with the RadScriptManager and see what scripts are downloaded, so you can make sure the same are present in your list.

Also, do you get script errors? If so - what? The toolkitScriptManager is no longer compatible with asp:ScriptManager and I am not sure what problems this may bring. Most likely, you can find an alternative to the ACT control in the Telerik suite or jQuery so you could drop it and stop having such issues with integrating it.